# LabView: Dynamic plant model for EKF

Tags: labview, kalman-filter

I need some help regarding wiring a plant model to an EKF block in LabVIEW. I have checked the sample VIs but the problem is that in my application the matrices A, B and C used to represent the model in EKF are time dependent and changes as the simulation progresses. However in the provided samples plant models are taken as static reference VI which does not changes with time. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the toolkit that's being used. Can post an image of the example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with labview, but I am familiar with kalman filters and programming languages like C, Java etc.  If I was working from an example which was using static objects (i.e. your matrices A, B, C) and I needed them to change on each kalman filter cycle, I'd just delete the static objects and add them as parameters to all the relevant functions.

If doing that doesn't solve your problem, then I think you need to give lots more detail about the problem that you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for this issues especially from LabVIEW perspective. Limitation is that LabVIEW is only taking plant model as a reference of a VI which is static. However in my case it need to change with time.